# How can i profile queries that contains 'password'

Tags: sql-server, profiler

SQL Server Profiler 2008R2 does not show queries that contains 'password'.
it shows "'password' was found in text of this event. The text has been replaced with this comment for security".

any idea why SQL Server profiler does not let me to profile my server and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the database server also SQL 2008, or is it older? (use `SELECT @@VERSION` to check)

Comment: just a simple search away: http://serverfault.com/questions/145519/how-do-i-get-sql-profiler-to-show-statements-with-column-names-like-password#145524

Comment: the engine is SQL 2000